# Nginx Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () to png files

Tags: wordpress, nginx

A WordPress site with nginx(1.18.0).

The theme settings page does not display [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeVWO.png) (images exist and are located in the folder, folder and file [permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUUMF.png)are 755 and 644). The problem is only in the theme settings(newspaper - https://themeforest.net/item/newspaper/5489609), otherwise, the site works fine.

How to fix it?

````
server {
        root /var/www/website;
        client_max_body_size 32m;
        
        # SSL configuration
        #
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;

        ssl_certificate         /var/www/website/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /var/www/website/priv.key;
        ssl_client_certificate /var/www/website/cloudflare.crt;
        ssl_verify_client on;

        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
        pagespeed on;
        pagespeed Domain "https://website";
        pagespeed FileCachePath "/var/cache/ngx_pagespeed/";
        # pagespeed RewriteLevel OptimizeForBandwidth;
        pagespeed LoadFromFile "https://website/" "/var/www/website/";
        pagespeed FetchHttps enable,allow_self_signed;
        pagespeed EnableFilters make_google_analytics_async,combine_javascript,combine_css; # https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-make-google-analytics-async
        pagespeed LowercaseHtmlNames on; # https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/configuration#lower_case

        location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" {
                add_header "" "";
        }

        location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_static/" { }
        location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }

        pagespeed SslCertDirectory "/var/www/website/";
        pagespeed SslCertFile "cert.pem";

        server_name website;

        index index.php;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

            location ~* ^(/wp-content/.+)\.(png|jpe?g)$ {
            set $base $1;
            set $webp_uri $base$webp_suffix;
            set $webp_old_uri $base.$2$webp_suffix;
            set $root "/var/www/website";
            root $root;
            add_header Vary Accept;
            if ( !-f $root$webp_uri ) {
                add_header X_WebP_SP_Miss $root$webp_uri;
            }
            try_files $webp_uri $webp_old_uri $uri =404;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
        location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }

        location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
                deny all;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|webp|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
        }

        location = /xmlrpc.php { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; return 444; }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
} ```
````